# With multiple notifications on screen, closing a notification closes the last notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

I am using [NOTY](http://ned.im/noty/) (notification library) version [3.0.0](https://github.com/needim/noty/releases/tag/v3.0.0) to show notification popups from JavaScript.

While having multiple notifications on the screen, when I click the close button, it always closes the last notification placed on screen. I know this is because the variable n is always overwritten by the last notification object in the sample code. But, I didn't find any clue in the documentation about how to handle notification close in case of multiple notifications.

Should I create an array of notification objects and then calling the .close() function like this n[i].close(), or do we have any better way to achieve this?
Help please.

Sample code:

```
var n = new Noty({
    type: 'success',
    layout: 'bottomRight',
    theme: 'relax',
    text: "<b>Testing 2<br/><br/> ",
    timeout: false,
    closeWith: ['button'],
    animation: {
        open: 'noty_effects_open',
        close: 'noty_effects_close'
    },
    buttons: [
        Noty.button('CLOSE', 'btn btn-error', function () {
            console.log('button 2 clicked');
            n.close();
        })
      ],
}).show();
```

Comment: I think you should keep just 1 notification open at a time. Close the older one before showing the new one

Comment: This is not an option for me. Client needs to display multiple notifications at a time.

Comment: there is a `queue` option where you can keep multiple popups opened

Comment: Yeah, you should use an array for storing notifications. But, it would be nice to have access Noty's itself in button's callback. I will implement that enhancement in next version of Noty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `queue` functionality where in you can push multiple objects to a queue variable and can manipulate those using below examples

```
Noty.closeAll(); // Closes all notifications
Noty.closeAll('myCustomQueueName'); // Closes all notifications with queue named 'myCustomQueueName'

Noty.setMaxVisible(10); // Sets the maxVisible notification count for global queue;
Noty.setMaxVisible(10, 'myCustomQueueName'); // Sets the maxVisible notification count for 'myCustomQueueName' queue;
```

Comment: That's a good idea. But, does the queue option is intended to be used for this purpose, I don't think so? Anyway, if we don't have any other solution this is a good alternate.